# Are async functions that are used inside event listeners bottlenecked by the event themselves?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Assume I have a function that logs to the console after each input. The usage of this is, for example, appending items to a list then setting a timer for them to be removed.

```js
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const button = document.querySelector('#click-me');

async function removeSomething(after) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('I fired after' + after.toString());
  }, after);
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  removeSomething(getRandomInt(500, 2500));
});
```

```html
<button id="click-me">Click me.</button>
```

When I declare a function `async`, I assume it scopes out of the main event and is able to run behind to allow other things to run, but the thing is, if that function is used within an event listener, assume I clicked that button 50 times a second, what would be the bottle-neck? The CPU that can't handle the 50 click events or my function?

I'm trying to understand the interaction between blocking & non-blocking code.

Comment: You don't need an async function if you don't use await or return something

Comment: Check this: https://dev.to/steelvoltage/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd

Answer (score 1):

> When I declare a function async, I assume it scopes out of the main event and is able to run behind to allow other things to run

No! There is no such thing as a "background". JS is *single threaded²*. Making the function `async` is a no op here. It doesn't change anything.

> if that function is used within an event listener, assume I clicked that button 50 times a second, what would be the bottle-neck? The CPU that can't handle the 50 click events or my function?

Um, all the code you write *runs on your CPU*?

> I'm trying to understand the interaction between blocking & non-blocking code.

All code you write runs on the only thread JS has. Therefore all the code you write *blocks that thread*. If you however start an asynchronous task, the engine will offload that (the task, not your handler) to another thread / hardware that is out of your reach, therefore attaching a callback or `await` ing a promise is *non-blocking*, as execution of the current code ends, the engine can execute other code, and then if the async task finishes, it *runs the callback or continues the `async function` execution* (which itself is blocking too).

---

Example 1: A callback from a timer:

```
  console.log(1);
  setTimeout(() => console.log(3), 1000);
  console.log(2);

 // Chain of actions:
 // Execution of the global scope:
 console.log(1);
 setTimeout(/*...*/, 1000); // Send timer task to some underlying mechanism, e.g. hardware timers
 console.log(2);
 // Execution of global scope ends

 // Engine goes on with other stuff

 // Timer finishes, callback gets called:
 (() => console.log(3))()
 // Callback ends
```

Example 2: Awaiting a fetch call:

```
  (async function task() {
     const req = await fetch("http://example.com");
     const result = await req.json();
  })();

  // Chain of actions:
 // Execution of the global scope
 (async function task() {
    /* halted here */ await fetch("http://example.com"); // Offloaded to some IO thread
    // Implicitly return promise
 })();
 // Execution of global scope ends

 // Engine goes on with other stuff

 // Response arrived from the server via some IO thread, execution continues:
    const req = /*the result*/
    /*halted*/ await req.json();
 // Execution ends

 // Engine goes on with other stuff

 // Response parsed, execution continues
 const result = /*the result*/
 return result; // Promise resolves
 // Execution ends
```

---

<sub>² Actually it isn't, it does however have an "observably synchronous execution model". "JS is single threaded" is the (over)simplified version of that</sub>

Comment: I get it and reading through that, it's what I meant...just...without the dumb words, sorry - I don't know what I don't know. Is it wrong to think that whatever I'd wrap inside an `async` function gets pushed in the back? I'm in the mindset of thinking that I can put just about anything inside of it and it'll work like that.

Comment: I understand, but then how can you make 2 functions not be blocked by one another while still respecting the order of calls? Iirc, the event loop has the call stack and the Web APIs thread pools to work with, so, no matter how much I'd try to delegate, say, first function, go to the call stack, second one to Web APIs, there's still some waiting to be done.